# Java synchronisation and threads

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ClassA{
  int a = 0, b = 10;
  Random rand = new Random();

  public synchronized void add(){
      if (a < 10){ 
         a++;
         b--;
      };
  }

  public synchronized void subtract(){
      if (b < 10){ 
         b++;
         a--;
      }
  }
  
  public synchronized boolean check(){
     return a + b == 10;
  }
  
  
  public static void main(String args[]){
      
      ClassA a = new ClassA();
      
      B ba = new B(a);
      B bb = new B(a);
      
       //notice these two threads are not associated with the object a!
      Thread t11 = new Thread(bb);
      Thread t22 = new Thread(ba);
      t11.start(); 
      t22.start();
  }
}


class B implements Runnable{
    ClassA a;
    
    B(ClassA a){
        this.a = a;
    }
   
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while (a.check()){
          if (a.rand.nextInt(2) == 1)
              a.subtract();
          else
              a.add();
      } System.out.print("Out of sync");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand java multi-threading better. So, I know that the saying goes only one thread can access an object instance and thus call that instance's method (in this case for example, the `subtract` method in class `classA`.

But what happens when, you still have the same instance of `classA`, `a` but two threads associated with a different class `classB` altogether trying to call `a`'s methods? I expected that the message `out of sync` would never have been printed, but it did. Afterall, there's still only one object instance `a`, does that imply synchronization doesn't apply in this example?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `out of sync` would never be printed, because for your situation, the multithreading is implemented correctly: The critical methods that perform a sequence of operations and are thus not atomic are made behave like atomic methods by the using the `synchronized` keyword on the method.

Assume a code block is declared `synchronized (x)`.
The first thread that enters this code block obtains the lock of object `x` and happily executes that code block.

Any non-first thread that tries to enter the block on the same object `x` is "suspended" by putting the thread in the *lock pool* of `x`. As soon as the thread that currently has the lock leaves the `synchronized (x)` block, a random thread from the lock pool becomes the next thread to execute that block.

When using `synchronized` on an instance method, it is effectively the same as wrapping the entire content of the method with `synchronized (this)`. (For `static` methods, it would be the class object of the enclosing class.)

So, in your case, there is one instance of class `A`, and all synchronization happens on it.

If you want to see the `out of sync` message, try removing the `synchronized` keyword. Then after some time you should see the expected `out of sync` message.

Sidenotes:

- Because `out of sync` is a message, it should probably be printed on `System.err`, not `System.out`.
- Instead of `a.rand.nextInt(2) == 1`, you could use `a.rand.nextBoolean()`.
- Having `class B` access field `rand` of `class A` breaks encapsulation, you might want to give `class A` a method `randomBoolean()` which does `return rand.nextBoolean()`, and call that method `randomBoolean()` from `class B`.
- Having the same variable names with different meanings in different contexts may be confusing. In `class A`, the variables `a` and `b` denote two numbers, in other contexts, the variables `a` and `b` refer to instances of `class A` and `class B`. Consider renaming the fields of `class A` to something else, like `number1` and `number2`.

Comment: "Assume a code block is declared synchronized (x). The first thread that enters this code block obtains the lock of object ...." Sorry, but what about code outside a code block? Suppose you have a method ```public void f(){                                                                                                                          
                val++;    synchronized(this){ anotherVal++;} }```.  In this case how can you say "the thread that first enters the block obtains the lock of object x"? ( the variable ```val``` can still be modified by another thread, right?)